# Convert a heterogeneous list into a homogeneous list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance, optimization

How would you convert a heterogeneous list, e.g. `[1,"9",2,9,"109"]` to a homogeneous list, e.g. `[1,9,2,9,109]`?

The method I currently use is `[int(i) for i in listHere]`, but that is quite slow from what I can gather. Is there anything that converts everything at once?

Comment: It is the fastest and cheaper solution. why slow?

Comment: I found `list(map(int, listHere))` to be marginally faster

Comment: You have to iterate the whole list, but `map` is probably faster: `list(map(int, your_list))`

Comment: What do you call slow? What is the requirement?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy module and force type cast into int/float as per your wish and then reconvert to list if you need to.

here is a demo code

```
import numpy as np
x=[1,"9",2,9,"109"]
x=list(np.array(x,dtype='uint8'))
print(x)
```

and the output is `[1, 9, 2, 9, 109]`

Comment: How does this compare to `list(map(int, x))` in performance?

Comment: tested for an array of 100000000 length. map seem to be slightly faster although potentially if you needed to further calculations on a list you might want to stick with numpy arrays